# Source for Chasam Sofer quote about Zohar

Tags: sources-mekorot, authorship, zohar, quotations, chatam-sofer

What is the source for the Chasam Sofer having said (regarding the Zohar), "If we could sift the book and keep only what R’ Shimon Bar Yochai wrote, it would be a very very thin book. You would only have a few pages."?

Comment: Why the commentless down-votes?

Comment: @efraim it's a pretty terrible question post. Why should anyone think such a quotation exists that we should seek its source

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently it is quoted by one of the Chasam Sofer's students, Rabbi Eliezer Lipman Naizatts, in his sefer Mei Menuchot, page 43a, as having been said by the Chasam Sofer in front of many of his students.

Follow the link:
http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/06/chasam-sofers-position-that-zohar-is.html

Comment: Its arguably but the emes of the zohar isn't. Is the mechaber a fool? The gra? I don't think so.

Comment: @Brian Is Beit Shammai a fool for thinking you light chanuka candles descending? I don't think so. Welcome to Judaism where you can argue with people respectfully without thinking them to be a fool.

Comment: Bais Shammai's derech represents spiritually something unique and special. Well yes and no. On thinking people a fool, prob not the best idea. ,yes they can be wrong. That's why you need a Posek. There are diff valid Shitas, with diff approaches to life in general. If you for example decide ok I am going to suddenly do something not accepted by the majority in the Gemara.. then you are wrong. If you are eating Chicken with dairy ok you are wrong, and your food/dishes are not kosher. If you kill a flea on shabbos.. that's complicated and there are valid approaches in modern halach.