# Lag baomer and non-chasidic Jews

Tags: minhag, lag-ba-omer

Besides the *halakhot* (not saying *[tachanun](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%95),* possibility of weddings, cutting hair, listening to music etc.), were/are there any particular *Lag baomer* customs for non-mekubal/chasidic Jews? For example, I read the story of [R' Abraham ben Israel Rosanes](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12826-rosanes#anchor4), who went to Meron in 1867, and was [quite perplexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsherin) by the bonfires and the upsherins, while some Ashkenazim have [concerns](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81783/chasam-sofer-quote-about-zohar) regarding the Zohar.

Comment: "The idea of having an upsherin on Lag Ba'omer (particularly at the kever of the Rashbi) comes from the Arizal, as cited by R. Chaim Vital. I doubt these customs extend into the non-Hasidic Jewish world." Maybe not now. But of course R' Chayim Vital was no chasid. The question specifies "were/are" so you have an answer right there to the first half of that.

Comment: Upsherin has become fairly common among non-Hassidm during the past 30 years, from what I've seen. I can't tell you if there's a specific rise to do it specifically on Lag Ba'Omer. But the Jewish barbers in my neighborhood are crowded today! I'm sure that there are a few upsherenim (is that the plural??) for both kids as well as adults. I've heard of a "minhag" to chop down trees today as it's "Log" Ba'omer ;-)

Comment: Upsherin is a clearly chasidic custom that was taken from mekubalim in the Holy Land. I know that some non-chasidim do this, but it's not in the focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I located two customs mentioned in [this article](http://www.mazornet.com/holidays/Lagbomer/customs.htm):

> Bows and Arrows:  On Lag Baomer kids go out into the fields to play
>   with bows and arrows. There are two schools of thoughts as to what
>   this custom commemorates. One opinion cited in the Midrash is that
>   during the time of Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai no rainbow was seen.* It was
>   after the great flood that God promised Noah that he would never
>   bestow that kind of devastation on the world again. The rainbow,
>   according to Talmudic commentators appears when God deems the people
>   of the world as deserving severe punishment for wrongdoing. It was due
>   to Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai’s merit that the world was protected from
>   punishment and the warning sign of the rainbow was not needed. The
>   other reason given for youngsters going out into the fields to shoot
>   arrows is that it commemorates Bar Kochba’s temporary victory over the
>   Romans
>
> Eating Carobs   It is customary in some Jewish communities to eat
>   carobs on Lag B’omer. This is done to memorialize the miracle that
>   occurred to Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai and his son while they were hiding
>   in the cave, after fleeing Roman persecution. For thirteen years,
>   Rabbi Shimon and his son sustained themselves on carobs and water from
>   a tree and spring that God had miraculously provided for them.

The bows and arrows seems to be quite common among everyone including non-Chassidm. I haven't seen too many people eating carob on Lag Ba'Omer. After eating it on Tu B'Shevat, one trip to the dentist is enough ;-)

<sup>*</sup> [ירושלמי ברכות פרק ט הלכה ב גמרא](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1109.htm) - רבי חזקיה בשם רבי ירמיה כל ימיו של רבי שמעון בן יוחאי לא נראתה הקשת בענן