Is Moshe Idel’s scholarship considered kosher by the Orthodox Jewish community
I’m curious whether the scholarship of Moshe Idel, a contemporary scholar of Kabbalah, is considered kosher (i.e., that his scholarship doesn't contradict the Mesorah) and reliable (i.e., that a significant number of Orthodox rabbis/theologians vouch for his work) by the broader Orthodox Jewish community. If so, to what degree is his scholarship considered authoritative?

What is "kosher and reliable" and "considered authoritative" exactly and how would anyone measure it??

Kosher and reliable means that his scholarship doesn’t contradict the Mesorah, considered authoritative means a significant number of Orthodox Jews or Orthodox  Jewish Rabbis/theologians vouch for his work. Significant can be a semi arbitrary demarcation point, but clearly there is a line between fringe and mainstream scholarship even if a semi blurry one @DoubleAA

He's not a Kabbalist, if that's what you're wondering. In fact, I believe that most academic scholars of Kabbalah literature aren't Kabbalists. One of my rabbis once commented that Kabbalah academic scholars are like accountants: They know where all the money is but can't do anything with it. Oftentimes such scholars do not consider Kabbalah to have actual deep ramifications for how the world works. They study it because it interests them. But if you're interested in the history of Kabbalah from an academic POV, then he's one of the most well-known scholars nowadays.

@Harel13 I think academic scholars of Kabbalah get a big shrug from the Orthodox mainstream. Those who are "into" Kabbalah want a Kabbalist, and those who aren't don't really care about the academic scholarship about it.

In Likkutei Moharan, such people are referred to as, “Jewish-Scholar Demons”. (See 12:1:4, 12:1:6, 12:1:9 and 12:5:14-15, 12:6:1-6) for discussion about this.

The way the question is phrased is perhaps vague, but I can report having attended a lecture by Professor Idel at Yeshiva University's Revel graduate school. Revel itself does not 100% align with all of YU/RIETS Roshei Yeshivas' hashkafot, but there were many YU rabbis in attendance.
I should further point out that this lecture was not primarily focused on Idel's mysticism scholarship.
Professor Idel has said publicly and in personal correspondence that he is not orthodox. His writings explicitly indicate that he does not believe the preponderance of Zoharic material to be authored by Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai.

"His writings explicitly indicate that he does not believe the preponderance of Zoharic material to be authored by Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai." the same opinion of this as the Chasam Sofer then https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81783/3483

As already has been discussed in the comments, there is no doubt he is an academic. However, he does not present as "mekubal" and neither does any of his writings maintain any Rabbinic approbations.
Even the academic studies that discuss his approach to Kabbalah and Jewish outlook appear to note his apparent lack of orthodoxy. For example, here in the abstract it writes:

The article discusses the contribution of Moshe Idel’s vast research to the field of religious studies. The terms which best capture his overall approach are “plurality” and “complexity”. As a result, Idel rejects essentialist definitions of “Judaism”, or any other religious tradition.

